# How to find modulo inverse if two number are not relatively prime for Hill cipher?

Tags: cryptography

While practicing for Hill Cipher I choose a random Key matrix of $ 2*2 $ given as follows :
$ K = \begin{bmatrix}3&2\\1&0\\\end{bmatrix} $

Say the Text to Encrypt is **ATTACK** 
By using the Following Equation $ C=K * P \mod 26 $ I got the encrypted Text as **MAFTAC**, where

> $C$ is Cipher Text Matrix
>
> $K$ is Key Matrix
>
> $P$ is Plain Text Matrix

Now while decrypting the Cipher text using equation $ P= K ^{-1} * C \mod 26 $.

I need to find $ K^{-1} = |K|^{-1} Adj  A $ 
But The Multiplicative Inverse $ |K|^{-1}$  exist only if $ 26 $ and $|K|$ are relatively Prime. But In this case $|K|=-2= 24 \mod {26}$.

But 24 and 26 are not relatively Prime. Does That Mean The following Key Can't be used To Encrypt The Text?

Comment: This is not a research level question, but you could ask it on http://math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: But a hint: what happens when you try to encrypt the vector $P =\left[\begin{smallmatrix} 0 \\ 13 \end{smallmatrix} \right]$?

Comment: It will give me [A, A]

Comment: Yes, and so will [0,0].  So which of the two should be the result when you decrypt [A,A]?  You see the problem?

Comment: I understand That thing, but the question is that i am stuck with decrypting Any Text, because i need multiplicative inverse. and which doesn't exist in this case.

Comment: Yes, that's the whole point.  The non-invertibility means it's fundamentally impossible to recover a unique plaintext from a ciphertext.  There will always be multiple possibilities, with no way to know for sure which is the "right" one.

Comment: Thanks Nate, may be i need to switch the text book, that describes such concept properly.